# Why is RouteData.Values["someValue"] showing null in Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

My URL is this: `http://localhost:2570/Test/Index/5/100100/44`, where 5 = id, 100100 = jobno, and 44 = instid. However, when I try to access these values in the Controller all I get is null. What am I missing?

TestController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using InspectionWebFormsMVC.ViewModels;
using InspectionWebFormsMVC.Models;
using InspectionWebFormsMVC.Services;
using System.Data;

namespace Stuff.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        private WebFormsDataDbContext dbModels;

        public TestController()
        {
            dbModels = new WebFormsDataDbContext();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveEmailStatus(string empid, int? instid, long? emailid, long? ctrltypeid)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
            }

            var bar = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
            var blah = this.RouteData.Values["id"];
            var foo = this.RouteData.Values["instid"];
            int? iid = instid;
            int? formid = Convert.ToInt32(RouteData.Values["id"].ToString());
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = formid.Value, instid = iid.Value});
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Stuff.Models.Part>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Testing Editor Templates";
}

@using System.Web.WebPages;
@using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
@using Stuff.ViewModels;

<h2>Test Control for Webforms</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveEmailStatus", "Test", new { instid = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["instid"], empid = "107" }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div style="clear:both;">
        <div style="float:right;">
            <div style="text-align:left;">                
                @foreach (var line in ViewBag.EmailStatus as List<FormRowModel>)
                {
                    @line.Description.ToString()
                    <br /><br />
                    @line.RowInput[0].RowCtrl.DefaultValues[0].Label 
                    @: &nbsp; 
                    @line.RowInput[0].InputtedDate.ToString()
                    <br />  
                    @line.RowInput[1].RowCtrl.DefaultValues[0].Label 
                    @: &nbsp; 
                    @line.RowInput[0].InputtedData
                    <br /><br />
                    @Html.Hidden("emailid", line.RowInput[0].InputtedDataID)
                    @Html.Hidden("ctrltypeid", line.RowInput[0].RowCtrl.CtrlTypeID)
                }               
                <input type="submit" value="Send Email" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Global.asax.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Stuff
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "ProjectInfos", // Route name
                "ProjectInfo/{action}/{id}/{jobno}/{instid}/{section}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "ProjectInfo", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, jobno = UrlParameter.Optional, instid = UrlParameter.Optional, section = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "SectionsData", // Route name
                "Test/Sections/{id}/{jobno}/{instid}/{section}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "TestEdit", action = "Sections", id = UrlParameter.Optional, jobno = UrlParameter.Optional, instid = UrlParameter.Optional, section = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Sections", // Route name
                "Test/Index/{id}/{jobno}/{instid}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "TestEdit", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, jobno = UrlParameter.Optional, instid = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Pumps", // Route name
                "Home/Main/{id}/{jobno}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Main", id = UrlParameter.Optional, jobno = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Jobs", // Route name
                "Home/Jobs/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Jobs", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }
```

Comment: Do you have a route in Global.asax.cs that matches that route?

Comment: Your action also redirects to a non-existent action.

Comment: can you show the routes you have configured?

Answer (score 1):

From the code you have posted, the output of

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveEmailStatus", "Test", 
       new { instid = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["instid"], empid = "107" },
       FormMethod.Post))
```

would be

```
<form method="post" action="/Test/SaveEmailStatus?instid=44&empid=107">
```

So assuming the routes you have posted are correct, none of them will match that URL except the last (default) one. That route will have only 3 keys in RouteData, `controller`, `action` and `id`.

Since you're posting a form, you probably don't need `instid` and `empid` in your url, instead just post them as hidden inputs along with your form.

Comment: I see it now. I was assuming that the route information would get carried over to that ActionResult automagically. I need a route that matches that pattern to get those route values.